# printing matched patterns using unix commands

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, sed, grep

A co-worker came to me with a problem I thought would be trivial, but turned out to be challenging. The challenge is this: given an input string, what Unix commands can be used to print out any matching patterns within the string?

Let's say we have the following input string.

```
12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606
```

The goal is to print out any 5-digit or 6-digit numbers within the string, but not any 4-digit or 7-digit numbers.

We first thought of using sed like so:

```
echo "12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606" |
  sed 's/.*[^0-9]\{1\}\([0-9]\{5,6\}\).*/\1/g'
```

This command, however, only prints out the last occurrence of any matching patterns.

We finally came up with using a combination of sed and grep -Eo.

```
echo "12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606" |
  sed 's/^/ /' | sed 's/$/ /' | grep -Eo '[[:space:]]+[0-9]{5,6}[[:space:]]+' |
  sed 's/ $//' | sed 's/^ //'
```

It works but seem a bit kludgy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `tr` and `grep`?

```
echo "12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606" |
  tr ' ' '\n' |
  grep '^[[:digit:]]\{5,6\}$'
```

Or as dmckee suggests, you can use the `-o` flag to grep to skip the `tr` stage (if your version of `grep` has this flag):

```
echo "12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606" |
  grep -o '\<[[:digit:]]\{5,6\}\>'
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU grep at least supports `-o`, and I think it is in the POSIX version as well.

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.

Answer (score 0):

worked on linux box

```
echo "12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606"|egrep -o 's|[[:digit:]]{5,6} |p'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can actually do this using only Bash builtins, with no external utilities like `tr` or `sed` or `grep`:

```
INPUT='12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606'
( set -f
  for word in $INPUT ; do
    if [[ $word =~ ^[0-9]{5,6}$ ]] ; then
      echo $word
    fi
  done
)
```

(The `set -f` is to disable filename-expansion, so that we can split `$INPUT` into its component words without having to worry that it might contain a `*` or something that would expand into a list of filenames. The `( ... )` is to contain the effect of the `set -f`, so we don't have to worry about whether the surrounding context really wants filename-expansion to be disabled.)

Comment: Watch out for bash's `=~` operator. It has some [nasty corner cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700749/shell-program-code-about-regexp-and-file-handling/7700988#7700988).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606" |
sed 's/\<[0-9]\{,4\}\>//g;s/\<[0-9]\{7,\}\>//g;s/[^0-9]\+/ /g'
12345 789012 60606
```

Or:

```
echo "12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606" |
sed 'H;g;:a;s/\n\([0-9]\{5,6\}\)\> */\1 \n/;ta;s/\n[^ ]* /\n/;ta;s/..$//'
12345 789012 60606
```

Answer (score 0):

This filters each line, only printing out the 5 or 6 digit words, but keeping it on one line

```
 perl -ne 'print join(" ",grep /\b[0-9]{5,6}\b/, split)."\n";'
```

If input is

```
12345 4444 abc 789012 xyz 1234567 def 987654321 qrz 60606
hello
66666
```

Output is

```
12345 789012 60606

66666
```